# Retrieving single value data at Blade via Repository GONE WRONG

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I'm using Laravel 10 and I have made a table named `pages` which stores the all static pages field data of website.

Here is the table:

[image]

Now in order to retrieve this data, at the Controller I added this:

```
use App\Repositories\PageRepository;
use App\Models\Page;

class MainPagesController extends Controller
{
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(PageRepository $pageRepository)
    {
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $homeInfo = $this->pageRepository->getPageByType('home');
        return view('admin.pages.main.home', compact('homeInfo'));
    }
}
```

So I made a respository named `PageRepository.php` which goes like this:

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Page;

class PageRepository
{
    public function getPageByType(string $pageType)
    {
        return Page::where('pag_type', $pageType)->first();
    }

    public function getPageByName(string $pageName)
    {
        return Page::where('pag_name', $pageName)->first();
    }
}
```

So it looks nice and perfect but at the Blade, when I do this:

```
@dd($homeInfo->where('pag_name', 'hero_image')->first()->pag_value)
```

I get this error:

**Attempt to read property "pag_value" on null**

However, the `pag_name` with `hero_image` has already a value named `layer.png` and this error occurs for other `pag_name`s as well!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You already called the eloquent on the repository. then another eloquent  on @dd. try to change the dd to `$homeInfo->pag_value`

Comment: If you are trying to dd before the return view statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code `$homeInfo` is not a collection, it's a single `Page`  instance (`->first()`). So, you cannot chain `where` method on it.

use

```
public function getPageByType(string $pageType)
{
    return Page::where('pag_type', $pageType)->get();
}
```

and in your Blade file, you can use the `where` because `$homeInfo` will be a collection

```
@dd($homeInfo->where('pag_name', 'hero_image')->first()->pag_value)
```

Comment: one thing to note the second where is filtering on a collection not on the database

Answer (score 1):

When you called this on your controller

```
$homeInfo = $this->pageRepository->getPageByType('home');
```

It will only get one record from your database since you already called the method `->first()` from your repository.

So in your `$homeInfo` you can do this `$homeInfo->pag_value`.

Anyway to solve your problem, in your repository you can return the query object (don't call the `first` method yet).

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Page;

class PageRepository
{
    public function getPageByType(string $pageType)
    {
        return Page::where('pag_type', $pageType);
    }

    public function getPageByName(string $pageName)
    {
        return Page::where('pag_name', $pageName);
    }
}
```

Then your code in your blade file will work properly.